# Repair corrupted NTFS File System

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I am trying to recover data of of a failed archive drive for a friend. The drive resided in a NAS case to save important business info. The drive contains the only copy of the data. The case power supply failed rendering the case useless. The drive file table has been rendered corrupted in the process. Installing the drive in a new case and booting Windows displays the drive - but Windows Explorer asks you to insert a disk when it is clicked.

Switching to Ubuntu - drive does not mount properly (shows errors - unable to mount) Gparted shows the drive with an exclamation (partition error). Ran Testdisk and selected to Write partition table with no change. Ran Photorec which recovered a series of inch x inch image files of page size files (eg. cut an A4 page into inch x inch squares - get the point?).

I have an image of Gparted's error but not able to post due to my current forum rep level.

Switch back to Windows to try `chkdsk /f`, which gave an error drive not available.

Are there any other ways to recover or rebuils the partition table so I can successfully mount and recover the drive?

For interest sake, `sudo fdisk -l` displays:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x862715b5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *          63   488375999   244187968+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Also tried `sudo ntfs-3g -o force,rw /dev/sdd1 /home/andrew/recovery` and it says invalid parition, unable to mount.

Comment: Its best to make an image of the hard drive to work with, preserve what you have on the disk and work with the image when trying to recover data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found [MiniTool](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/partition-magic-for-windows7.html) Partition Wizard for Windows. It's a free program and it finally did the job. It could 'see' the drive I'm trying to recover and has a 'Check File System' button. It found 3 errors in the file system bitmap - which it fixed. File table repaired, File Explorer shows files, all good!

Comment: Thanks, Im trying this software right now, easeus data recovery was the only software that could recognize my hdd and it can also recover my data but it takes 10+ hours. Now thanks to you Ive found the second software that can recognize the drive. Minitool is checking right now for error on my partiton, lets hope it works

Comment: Not free anymore

Comment: MiniTool just uses chkdsk for it's file system repair behind the scenes. It literally outputs the raw chkdsk output.

Comment: Exactly, Minitool got praised here for no reason while, in this case, it is only a GUI for the windows check disk. Anything you did with the Minitool, you could have done without Minitool in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If I was you, I would take a look at [R-Studio](http://www.data-recovery-software.net/) which is my favourite recovery tool.

Just plug the drive in, select the disk (rather than partition), and it should be able to recover if it is possible.

There are other tools, and this one isn't free, but, it is by far my favourite.

Answer (score 0):

try test disk

this article shows you how to use it

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step